# how to have a one to many relationship entity deleted

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have 2 entity in my Symfony2 class:

```
class InstagramShopPicture
{
 /**
     * @Exclude()
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="InstagramPictureTag", mappedBy="picture", cascade={"remove"})
     */
    protected $tags;
}
```

and

```
class InstagramPictureTag
{


    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="InstagramShopPicture", inversedBy="tags")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="picture_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)
     */
    private $picture;
}
```

I wanted to make sure such that when I delete InstagramShopPicture the InstagramPictureTag also gets deleted. The issue now is that whenever I try to do that with the current setup, it always complaint about some foreign key issues. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Use the same `cascade={"remove"}` for the `$picture`. What is the `@Exclude()` in your mapping?

Comment: @Javad ignore the Exclude that is being used for serialization such that this doesn't get serialized

Comment: Then did `cascade={"remove"}` for `$picture` or any of the below answers helped?

Answer (score 0):

You need to define how to handle this deletion. [Check Docs](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/working-with-associations.html#orphan-removal)
In your case :

```
class InstagramShopPicture
{
 /**
     * @Exclude()
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="InstagramPictureTag", mappedBy="picture", orphanRemoval=true)
     */
    protected $tags;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can rely on Database level to handle it for you, by using [onDelete](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/working-with-associations.html#transitive-persistence-cascade-operations)

```
class InstagramShopPicture
{
    /**
    * @Exclude()
    * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="InstagramPictureTag", mappedBy="picture", onDelete="CASCADE")
    */
    protected $tags;
}
```